# Get/print current Ubercart currency via template.php

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

I am using Ubercart on D7.

Does anybody know how I can get the current Ubercart currency (e.g. $, €, etc) in template.php?

I am overriding the add to cart button via hook_form_alter, and need to print the site's current currency (in case of multi-currency) in the button markup.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_load().
 */
function NAME_OF_MY_MODULE_node_load($nodes, $types) {
    $language = $GLOBALS['language']->language;

    if($language == 'en') {
        $variables['uc_currency_code'] = 'EUR';
        $variables['uc_currency_sign'] = '€';
        $variables['uc_currency_thou'] = ' ';
        $variables['uc_currency_dec'] = ',';
        $variables['uc_currency_prec'] = '2';
        $variables['uc_sign_after_amount'] = 1;

        variable_realm_switch('currency', 'eur', $variables);

        // increase price by 1000
        foreach($nodes as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($value->price)) {
                $nodes[$key]->price += 1000;
                $nodes[$key]->sell_price += 1000;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Requires Variable module. I hope it helps